# Is there any method to open web app in MS Edge by default when i try to open through Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, model-view-controller, web-applications, microsoft-edge

My website's functions cannot be fully used by Internet Explorer. That is why I want to open my website through MS Edge by default when i want to open it through Internet Explorer?

Is there any method to proceed such action?

Comment: Add your tried code please it will help us

Comment: There is no any way to launch web app in MS Edge, If any user try to open it via Internet Explorer. You can try to inform us your issue in detail with sample code and steps. We will try to produce the issue and try to suggest possible solution. Thanks for your understanding.